# Список помеченных пунктов отобразить в респонсив форме

Tags: php, bootstrap

Есть список помеченных пунктов(может быть большой) и нужно его отобразить в [Responsive Form](http://www.bootply.com/jrNvaahcOh) (bootstrap).
Если есть 22 пункта должно быть что-то вроде :

- xs: 1 колонка со всеми элементами sm: 2 колонки по 11 элементов md: 3
  колонки 8, 8, 6 элементов lg: 4 колонки 6, 6, 6, 4 элементов

Полагаю, что нужно на сервере рассчитать 4 двумерных массива, а в темплейте делать 4 блока и отображать только один с помощью visible-xs и прятать остальные.
Можно ли в темплейте сделать как-то лучше ?  Вариант выше не нравится из-за необходимости делать 4 блоков...

Answer (score 3):

Если разобраться в гриде бутстрапа, то им очень легко пользоватся генерируя практически любые лайоуты. В вашем случае достаточно просто вставить каждый элемент в отдельную колонку, проблемма в данном случае может быть только с разной высотой элементов. Но это довольно просто решается

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            5
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
           6
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
           7
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            8
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            9
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            10
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            11
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            12
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            13
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            14
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            15
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            16
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Продолжать не буду, думаю понятно что вставлять в луп
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```